# SQLEXPRESS User password from hardcoded application

Tags: sql-server, password, password-recovery

I am setting up a new computer with an application which has a hardcoded password for the SQL database. I am not getting any help from the apllication provider because they want to do it themselves to make money.

On the old computer it is working fine. It has the application 'WinCar' which uses SQLEXPRESS 2005 - 2012. It has a hardcoded password so changing the user password in SQL is no option.

Is it possible to retrieve the password from the database. Even when is is hashed.

Thanks for your help.

Peter

Comment: if the above procedure doesn't work you can also try [SQL password recovery software](http://www.sqlserverdatabaserecovery.org/recover-lost-sql-password.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a SQL user login password (hashed) from one instance of SQL Server to another.

The stored procedure [sp_help_revlogin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) is a Microsoft stored procedure created for sql server migrations.
If you run it, it will give you a list of all the logins on a specific server (These are server logins, not the same as database users) with their hashed passwords.
You can copy the output directly into your target server, to migrate the user (with password).

However you really should be asking the developer of the application for support.
Going behind their back and asking for help online is a good way to get yourself in a situation where you have an app that's not working, and a vendor that won't help you anymore.